# Can't restore completed transactions for non-renewing subscriptions

Tags: ios, storekit

I have product with **Non-Renewing Subscription** type and I need functionality to restore transactions user previously made. I purchase several such products and want to restore them. I use this typical code:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

But I get `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` without any restored transaction. I use sandbox environment with test users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-renewing subscriptions are not restored by the iTunes app store.  It is your app's responsibility to track the user's subscription state -

From the [*In-App Purchase Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW5)

> Non-renewing subscriptions differ from auto-renewable subscriptions in a few key  ways. These differences give your app the flexibility to implement the correct
> behavior for your needs, as follows:
>
> Your app is responsible for calculating the time period that the
> subscription is active and determining what content needs to be made
> available to the user. Your app is responsible for detecting that a
> subscription is approaching its expiration date and prompting the user
> to renew the subscription by purchasing the product again.
>
> Your app is
> responsible for making subscriptions available across all the user’s
> devices after they’re purchased and for letting users restore past
> purchases. For example, most subscriptions are provided by a server;
> your server would need some mechanism to identify users and associate
> subscription purchases with the user who purchased them.

Comment: But I need to restore it, not renew. According to Apple's documentation this call asks the payment queue to restore previously completed purchases. There is no restriction for non-renewing subscriptions type in documentation.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer. I said "renewed" when I meant to say "restored", but if you refer to table 1-2 in the document I linked to you will see that non-renewing subscriptions are restored "by your app".